# Python, how to use KNNImputer from sklearn and impute data using groupby (filling missing values)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn

I have big data and I need to do imputation to fill out missing values. but I need to do imputation using groupby to fill missing values based on another column's value.
let's say I have this table

```
data = {'name':  ['Alex', 'Ben', 'Marry','Alex', 'Ben', 'Marry'],
        'job': ['teacher', 'doctor', 'engineer','teacher', 'doctor', 'engineer'],
        'age': [27, 32, 78,27, 32, 78],
        'weight': [160, 209, 130,164, 206, 132],
        'date': ['6-12-2022', '6-12-2022', '6-12-2022','6-13-2022', '6-13-2022', '6-13-2022']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data) df
```

I add data for the next day, but as null values, and I end up with this table:

```
    |name   |job        |age|weight |date
|---|-------|-----------|---|-------|--------
|0  |Alex   |teacher    |27 |160    |6-12-2022
|1  |Ben    |doctor     |32 |209    |6-12-2022
|2  |Marry  |engineer   |78 |130    |6-12-2022
|3  |Alex   |teacher    |27 |164    |6-13-2022
|4  |Ben    |doctor     |32 |206    |6-13-2022
|5  |Marry  |engineer   |78 |132    |6-13-2022
|6  |Alex   |teacher    |NaN|NaN    |6-14-2022
|7  |Ben    |doctor     |NaN|NaN    |6-14-2022
|8  |Marry  |engineer   |NaN|NaN    |6-14-2022
```

now if I want to fill out values for "age" and "weight" columns using KNNImputer or any other imputer, how can I do that while I groupby "name"?
As I mentioned the dataframe is a sample and I am dealing with big data
Appreciate any helps

Thanks

Comment: You can't directly use KNN and consider seasonality at the same time in a direct way. You either have to get output from KKNImputer and feed it into you own algorithm that assigns weights to certain days or you need to use a combination of KNN and time series models like ARIMA.

Comment: Also, why would you expect to have seasonality for age or weight?

Comment: Thanks @Pavel. How about just doing groupby without seasonality.?

Comment: hi @pavel , just removed the seasonality clause out of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mnm. The problem you posted is not straightforward to solve. The main starting problem is the fact that all numerical values are NaN and all remaining values are strings. The latter is rather inconvenient for KNN because there is no intuitive distance between strings.

I will (1) use a one-hot encoding for the job variable, and (2) label the consecutive days by 1, 2, and 3. Overall, this results in the following training and test data:

```
TRAINING
    name  teacher  doctor  engineer  age  weight  date
0   Alex        1       0         0   27     160     1
1    Ben        0       1         0   32     209     1
2  Marry        0       0         1   78     130     1
3   Alex        1       0         0   27     164     2
4    Ben        0       1         0   32     206     2
5  Marry        0       0         1   78     132     2



TEST
    name  teacher  doctor  engineer  age  weight  date
0   Alex        1       0         0  NaN     NaN     3
1    Ben        0       1         0  NaN     NaN     3
2  Marry        0       0         1  NaN     NaN     3
```

Clearly, this is not the only way to recode the `job` and `date` variable into numerical values. For example, you can easily ensure that consecutive days are only 1/365 apart. This essentially gives less weight to date differences when running the nearest neighbors algorithm.

The code below applies KNN to insert a single missing value into the table. To impute all missing observations:

1. Transform the code underneath "NEAREST NEIGHBORS" into a function.
2. Loop through the data the test data, identify a NaN, and impute using this function.

I hope this helps...

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor

############
### DATA ###
############
TrainingData = { 'name':  ['Alex', 'Ben', 'Marry','Alex', 'Ben', 'Marry'],
                'teacher': [1,0,0,1,0,0],
                'doctor': [0,1,0,0,1,0],
                'engineer': [0,0,1,0,0,1],
                'age': [27, 32, 78,27, 32, 78],
                'weight': [160, 209, 130,164, 206, 132],
                'date': [1,1,1,2,2,2]}

TestData = {'name': ['Alex', 'Ben', 'Marry'],
            'teacher': [1,0,0],
            'doctor': [0,1,0],
            'engineer': [0,0,1],
            'age': [np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],
            'weight': [np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],
            'data': [3,3,3]}
# Convert to pandas dataframe
dfTraining = pd.DataFrame(TrainingData)
dfTest = pd.DataFrame(TestData)
# Print
print(dfTraining)
print(dfTest)


#########################
### NEAREST NEIGHBORS ###
#########################
Variable2Predict = 'weight'
Person2Predict = 'Marry'

#### Step 1: Determine training data
# Select rows of beloning to Person2Predict
dfSubSelectedByName = dfTraining.loc[dfTraining['name'] == Person2Predict]
# Assign dependent variable as the variable to predict
Y = dfSubSelectedByName[Variable2Predict].to_numpy()
# Nearest neighbor computation should be based on all columns in the data except 'name' and the variable to predict
X = dfSubSelectedByName[dfSubSelectedByName.columns[~dfSubSelectedByName.columns.isin(['name', Variable2Predict])]].to_numpy()
print(X)

### Step 2: Nearest neighbor prediction
K = 1
# Read row from pandas dataframe based on name
Row2Predict = dfTest.loc[dfTest['name'] == Person2Predict]
# Select all variable except for name and dependent variable
Xpred = Row2Predict[Row2Predict.columns[~Row2Predict.columns.isin(['name', Variable2Predict])]].to_numpy()

# Step 3: K-NN based on the observed variables
PresentVariables = ~np.isnan(Xpred)
NumberOfPresentVariables = np.sum(PresentVariables)
NearestNeighbor = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=K).fit(X[:, PresentVariables[0]], Y)
Yhat = NearestNeighbor.predict( np.reshape( Xpred[PresentVariables], (1,NumberOfPresentVariables) ) )
print(Yhat)
```

Comment: hi @hanno-reuvers thanks for your help, a quick question, so what if instead of choosing each name, I want to do groupby a column, like in this case to do groupby('name')? appreciate your help. thanks

Comment: @mnm I suspect you can use pandas to select the training data based on more complex selection rules. As long as the numpy arrays Y and X have valid formats, I expect all to work well (but haven't tried myself).

Comment: so basically I could change Y to:  Y=df_train.groupby('msisdn')['dcr'].apply(lambda x: (x.to_numpy())), correct?

Comment: also changed these as follow: X_pred=df_test_x.groupby('msisdn').apply(lambda x: (x.to_numpy())),   PresentVariables = X_pred.loc[X_pred.notnull()]   but then I have problem with PresentVariables[0],

Comment: yes as I mentioned, I get error "KeyError: 'key of type tuple not found and not a MultiIndex'" for using X[:, PresentVariables[0]]